# Range of numbers in AngularJS not rendering with variable

Tags: angularjs, arrays, loops, scope

I can already render a list of numbers in angular using the following code in my controller

```
$scope.range = function(n) {
 return new Array(n);
};
```

and I use it like so

```
<ul>
  <li class="ticked" ng-repeat="a in range(10) track by $index">{{$index + 1}}</li>
</ul>
```

and it draws 10 pretty

```
<li>1</li> 
...
...
<li>10</li>
```

as expected

Now I when I am trying to use this code with a scope variable instead of ten i.e

```
item.itemTickCount
```

If I output `{{item.itemTickCount}}` I see 13 but when I try to render

```
<ul>
  <li class="ticked" ng-repeat="a in range(item.itemTickCount) track by $index">{{$index + 1}}</li>
</ul>
```

I just get 1 `<li></li>` when it should be 13

What am I doing wrong.

Note I have already tried

```
range(itemTickCount)
range({{item.itemTickCount}})
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. see https://embed.plnkr.co/7xenEAclUTOUPNDl6e6c/ , range with a custom variable. Also, I have never heard of `track by` syntax, AngularJS marks this as an error so I removed it. idk.

Comment: Thanks for the level of effort. I will try this tomorrow when back in front of laptop

Comment: your `item.itemTickCount` is probably a string, but should be an integer.

Comment: see [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/k1l6WydjiIBA0QlljTjV?p=preview) which illustrates this

Comment: @Blauhirn that's because you are using an ancient version of angular in your demo. `track by` helps performance and removes problems due to duplicates and is highly recommended. Read `ng-repeat` docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string....cast it to number

```
$scope.range = function(n) {       
    return new Array(+n||0);
};
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/L0lQrtN8sLQfMjM2TDc2?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: DOH! I exposed the JSON and you are correct! "itemTickCount" : "13", changing the function to yours and it now works fine

Comment: note what happens though if you enter decimal like `11.2` ... might need some fine tuning for validation/rounding